# How to determine a functional dependency for the variance in regression

Tags: regression, variance

I am trying to analyze measurements that look like this:
[image]

The date seems to be correlated linearly. And a can surely use linear regression to find a trend line as shown in the picture.

However, I also think that there is a correlation between the x-value of the data points and the deviation of the points from the trend line.

How can I analyze this correlation formally?

Maybe it is possible to find both, the median and the standard deviation, as functions of x?

**Additional question:**

How would I go about aggregating or visualizing this date?
If the data points were one dimensional (no different x values), I would use a box and whisker plot.
Is there something like a two-dimensional counterpart to the box and whisker plot?

Comment: you may have a case of multiplicative errors, e.g. $y=X\beta\varepsilon$